# Read a file with 2048 bytes

Tags: java, file-io

Guys i have a file which has only one line. The file has no encoding it is a simple text file with single line.

For every `2048 byte in a line` , there is new record of `151 byte (totally 13*151 byte = 1945 records + 85 byte empty space)`. similarly for the next 2048 bytes.

What is the best file i/o to use? i am thinking of reading 2048 bytes from file and storing it 
in an array .

```
while (offset < fileLength &&(numRead=in.read(recordChunks, offset,alength)) >= 0) 
{ 
}
```

how can i get from the read statement only 2048 bytes at a time . i am getting IndexOutofBoundException.

Comment: Your question is unclear. It's not obvious what problem you're having, or in what sense this is really a "line" (given that lines are associated with text, but you're giving *byte* counts). Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: if u have a byte array why can't you read the first 2 bytes with index 0 and 1

Comment: @Pangeo thanks , i forgot that.  @skeet thanks for the link , reading it.:)

Answer (score 4):

Just use a [FileInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), the various `read` methods will allow you to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
byte byte1 = dataArray[0];
byte byte2 = dataArray[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, the easiest way to read data from a file is to use a BufferedReader :

```
try
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your_file"));

    //Read the first line
    String s = br.readLine();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then just do what you want with the String you get !

Hope this helps.

Comment: This may not work as expected due to file encodings. It sounds like the OP wants to read bytes, not Strings.

Comment: Adrian is right, from my experience FileReader is *evil*. One should always prefer `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(...), ENCODING)` (+bufferization)